# Deadlock error while running SSIS package from SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting this error: "A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variable "User:vFileExists" for read access. A lock could not be acquired after 16 attempts and timed out". **This does not happen when the package is run individually, but only when it is run from SQL Server Agent Job.** I don't have any event handlers.

[image]

[image]

```
 Public Sub Main()
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '
    If Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables("vSourceFilePath").Value.ToString, Dts.Variables("vFileNamePattern").Value.ToString).Length > 0 Then
        Dts.Variables("User::vFileExists").Value = True
        Dts.Variables("User::vFileList").Value = Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables("vSourceFilePath").Value.ToString, Dts.Variables("vFileNamePattern").Value.ToString)
    End If

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    Dts.Variables.Unlock()

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This should help: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/bradleyschacht/2013/03/12/ssis-2012-deadlock-when-running-ssis-from-sql-agent-job/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post on the matter: http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/A-deadlock-was-detected-while-trying-to-lock-variables-in-SSIS.aspx

Try playing around with the scope of the variables so that they only live where they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue was with permissions. The account running the SSIS job from SQL server agent did not have read/write permission for the server where the ssis package extracted the files from.